# How do I an extra widget in between SliverAppBar and SliverList/Grid?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, sliver-grid

I want to add a similar item between my SliverAppBar and SliverList. I tried using a regular Row, but it kept throwing an exception. I know about SliverPadding, so I was wondering if there's something similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try SliverToBoxAdapter, [reference](https://medium.com/flutter-community/slivers-deep-dive-series-slivertoboxadapter-sliverlist-and-sliverfixedextentlist-80c2f1ad2f93):

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Row
)
```